# Probability of repeating at least 2 digits

Tags: probability, statistics

Pin codes consist of 4 digits between 0 and 9.
If a pin-code were generated by a random number generator (e.g. by 4 ten-sided dice), what is the probability that it will have at least two digits that repeat?

Comment: Does 1272 have two digits that repeat according to your definition, or is it only things like 1227 you're after?

Comment: Sample of pin codes consisting at least 2 digits that repeat:
1494, 1444, 4444, 4499, etc.
so 1272 and 1227 are both in the sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier to compute the probability of the opposite event, namely that you get four *different* digits.

Imagine that you choose the digits one by one by rolling a singe ten-sided die. You win if some digit appears twice. What is the chance of *losing*? In order to lose, all of the following must be true:

- The first digit is some digit.
- The second digit is different from the first digit, which happens with probability 9/10.
- The third digit is different from the two first ones. They are already known to be different, so this happens with probability 8/10.
- The fourth digit is different from the tree first ones, which happens with probability 7/10.

So the probability of losing is $\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{8}{10}\cdot\frac{7}{10}=\frac{9\cdot 8\cdot 7}{1000} = 0.504$

The chance of winning is one minus this.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  There are $10^4$ total codes.  To not duplicate, you have $10$ choices for the first number, $9$ for the second, and ???